# how to flip a sprite in c#

Tags: c#, sprite

I'm making a little game based on XNA game development's tutorial game "shooter"... after a bit of trial and error, I made my own animated sprite that i can move around the screen. The problem is, he's always facing right.

How can i change this (image below) so that he faces the right direction every time the key event is pressed?!

I'm pretty new to C# as you might have guessed, and I realize this may be more complicated than i thought, so i just need to know how to make the sprite face right when moving right and left when he's moving left.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeFih.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: never, never call your functions something like IDFK. It'll be hell to maintain.

Comment: @Dhaivat Pandya: Pretty sure that was just to get the point across, i.e., "I don't F@#$ing know".

Comment: That was a placeholder for a working event that would change the player's direction... there's nothing in this document named IDFK

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this by passing the `SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally` option to your`SpriteBatch.Draw()` method.  But as others have said this will have more overhead than using a sprite sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a sprite sheet will contain images for each direction.  You can flip the image at runtime, but it adds image processing that is unnecessary.  I would suggest to you that you simply create a sprite sheet up front with each animation baked in and just figure out which frame to display at runtime.

[See an example of a simple sprite sheet here](http://www.echostorms.net/Resources/Misc/misc%20RMVX%20resources/Sprite-1.png)

Comment: Sprite sheets are the way to go, one cell for each direction

Comment: So then, how would I change which frames are played at what time?

Comment: @Jay Riggs: Haha, yeah, I found another.

Comment: @Zanrkvil: You create a simple function to figure out which frame to display.  For example, if the character is facing right you know that you have to grab a frame from the third row (per my example image).

Answer (score 0):

```
SpriteEffects s = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
int smX = 200; //smx is the 'x' coordinates.

    public void runChar()
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            smX -= 2;
            s = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
            //oposite direction.
        }
        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            smX += 2;
            s = SpriteEffects.None;
            //original direction.
        }
    }

spriteBatch.Draw(sM, new Rectangle(smX, 200, 100, 100), null, Color.White, rotation, new Vector2(50, 50), s, 0f);
```

This will 'flip' the texture left and right.